# async.waterfall inside a for loop escapes the for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

On a `Form Action` of type `POST`, we fetch all the values in `Node.JS/Express` and try saving it into `MongoDB`.

A hidden field determines the length of a property from the frontend javascript and it's value is updated as the hidden field's value.

This length is used in the backend (Node) to iterate over a list of items.

I have a `async.waterfall` function and a `for loop` running inside it like this.

```
async.waterfall([
function(callback){
       var itemLength = req.body.itemLength;
        var itemProp,itemComponent;
        var destination;
        var destinationsArray =[];

        for(var k=1; k<=itemLength; k++){

            destination = new Destination({
                name: req.body['destinationName'+k],
            });

            itemComponent = {
              "itemCompProp" : req.body['itemCompProp'+k]
            };


            itemProp = new ItemProp({
               itemComponent: itemComponent
            });

            itemProp.save(function(err,itemPropSaved){
              destination.newProperty = itemPropSaved._id

              destination.save(function(err,destinationSaved){
                if(err){
                  console.log("Error== " + err);
                }
                else{
                  destinationsArray.push(destinationSaved._id);
                }
              });

            });
         }// End of For
  callback(null,destinationsArray);
},
function(destinationsArray,callback){
   var brand = new Brand({
    name : req.body.brandName,
  });

  brand.save(function(err,brandSaved){
      if(err){
          console.log("Error== " + err);
        }else{
            console.log('Brand Saved');
        }
   });
   callback(null);
}
], function (err, status) {
  if(err){
    req.flash('error', {
          msg: 'Error Saving Brands'
      });

     console.log("Error : " + err); 
  }  
  else{
      console.log("Brand Saved."); 
      req.flash('success', {
          msg: 'Brand Successfully Added!'
      });
  }
});

res.redirect('/redirectSomewhere');
```

When we run this, The `destinationsArray` is returned first as `null`, as opposed to going through the `for loop` and then returning the proper value of `destinationsArray` over a length (`itemLength`) of destinations.

We want the process to be synchronous. We also tried using a closure wrapping the `for Loop` but to no avail.

We can't use a `async.eachSeries` instead of the `for Loop` as I am just iterating over a numeric property and we don't have any `documents to iterate over`

Any feasible solution to run a `for Loop` inside a `async.waterfall`?

Cheers and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with the code you have there:

1. where the callbacks got called.
2. where res.redirect() got call.
3. the **for** loop.

save() is asynchronous.  Regular **for** loop will just continue without waiting for all save() calls to finish.  That's why destinationsArray is empty.  As you said, you cannot use async.eachSeries() since you're iterating through numeric property.  However, you're on the right track there.  Async.whilst() does just that.  Here is the revised code with Async.whilst() and proper calling locations of the callbacks:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    var itemLength = req.body.itemLength;
    var itemProp,itemComponent;
    var destination;
    var destinationsArray =[];
    var k = 1;  // 1st part of for loop:  for(k=1; k<=itemLength; k++)

    async.whilst(
      function() {
        return k <= itemLength;  // 2nd part of for loop:  for(k=1; k<=itemLength; k++)
      },
      function(whilstCb) {
        destination = new Destination({
          name: req.body['destinationName'+k]
        });

        itemComponent = {
          "itemCompProp" : req.body['itemCompProp'+k]
        };

        itemProp = new ItemProp({
          itemComponent: itemComponent
        });

        itemProp.save(function(err,itemPropSaved){
          destination.newProperty = itemPropSaved._id

          destination.save(function(err,destinationSaved){
            if(err){
              console.log("Error== " + err);
            } else {
              destinationsArray.push(destinationSaved._id);
            }
            k++;  // 3rd part of for loop:  for(k=1; k<=itemLength; k++)
            whilstCb(null);
          });
        });
      },
      function(err) {
        // It gets here once the loop is done
        console.log(destinationsArray);  // This array should have all the values pushed
        callback(null, destinationsArray);
      }
    );
  },
  function(destinationsArray,callback){
    var brand = new Brand({
      name : req.body.brandName
    });

    brand.save(function(err,brandSaved){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error== " + err);
      } else {
        console.log('Brand Saved');
      }
      callback(null);
    });
  }
], function (err, status) {
  if(err){
    req.flash('error', {
      msg: 'Error Saving Brands'
    });
    console.log("Error : " + err);
  } else {
    console.log("Brand Saved.");
    req.flash('success', {
      msg: 'Brand Successfully Added!'
    });
  }
  res.redirect('/redirectSomewhere'); 
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Perfect. Thanks a ton! Didn't know about `async.whilst`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with `callback(null, destinationsArray);` getting called outside the `for loop` without checking first to see the loop has been finished.

Try replacing `callback(null, destinationsArray);` with something like this:

```
if (itemLength > 0 && destinationsArray.length === k - 1)  {
    callback(null, destinationsArray);
} else {
    callback(true);
}
```

The above checks to make sure the `destination.save()` gets completed the proper number of times successfully.

I actually prefer the method proposed by djskinner. However, because of the `console.log()` that occurs when there is a `save()` error, the callbacked `destinationsArray` could possibly hold the incorrect number of items. To fix this, you could make sure to replace the `console.log("Error== " + err);` with something like `callback(err)` to end the waterfall with the error returned. In addition, the `k === itemLength` check doesn't properly account for the correct number of items that should be saved. This should be replaced with `k === destinationsArray.length`.

I made modifications to fix this and posted an updated version below.

```
destination.save(function(err, destinationSaved){
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
    else {
        destinationsArray.push(destinationSaved._id);
        if (k === destinationsArray.length) {
            callback(null, destinationsArray);
        }
    }
});
```

**--EDIT--** I really like the solution that Ben posted using `whilst()`. This allows the creation of a loop where the iterations runs serially. For more info, view the npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#whilst).

Answer (score 1):

Its not so much the for loop that is causing you problems but that `save` is an asynchronous operation. The for loop completes and the callback is executed before any of the `save` callbacks have had chance to complete.

What you want to do is call the `async.waterfall` callback after all the destination save callbacks have been executed. Something like:

```
         destination.save(function(err,destinationSaved){
            if(err){
              console.log("Error== " + err);
            } else {
              destinationsArray.push(destinationSaved._id);
              if (k === itemLength) {
                  // all destination callbacks have completed successfully
                  callback(null, destinationsArray);
              }
            }
          });
```